# can my code for reversing link list be further enhanced

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

Here is my program which creates a link list and also reverses it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *list=NULL;
struct node *root=NULL;
static int count=0;
struct node *create_node(int);//function to create node
void travel_list(void);
void create_list(int);
void reverse_list(void);
int main()
{
    int i, j, choice;
    printf("Enter a number this will be root of tree\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    create_list(i);
    printf("Enter  1 to enter more numbers \n 0 to quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice!=0){
     printf("Enter a no for link list\n");
        scanf("%d",&i);
//  printf("going to create list in while\n");
    create_list(i);
        travel_list(); 
    printf("Enter  1 to enter more numbers \n 0 to quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("reversing list\n");
     reverse_list();
     travel_list();
 }


// end of function main
void create_list (int data)
{
 struct node *t1,*t2;
 //printf("in function create_list\n");
 t1=create_node(data);
 t2=list;
 if( count!=0)
 {
   while(t2->next!=NULL)
   {
   t2=t2->next;
   }
 t2->next=t1;
 count++;
 }
 else 
  {
   root=t1;
   list=t1;
   count++;
  }
}
struct node *create_node(int data)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->data=data;
    temp->next=NULL;
  //      printf("create node temp->data=%d\n",temp->data);
//  printf("the adress of node created %p\n",temp);
    return temp;
}
void travel_list(void )
{
 struct node *t1;
 t1=list;
 printf("in travel list\n");
 while(t1!=NULL)
 {
 printf("%d-->",t1->data);
 t1=t1->next;
 }
 printf("\n");
}
void reverse_list(void)
{
    struct node *t1,*t2,*t3;
       t1=list;
    t2=list->next;
    t3=list->next->next; 
   int reverse=0;
   if(reverse==0)
   {
    t1->next=NULL;
    t2->next=t1;
    t1=t2;
    t2=t3;
    t3=t3->next;
    reverse++;

    }


    while(t3!=NULL)
     {

     t2->next=t1;
    t1=t2;
    t2=t3;
    list=t1;
    travel_list();
    t3=t3->next;
    }
    t2->next=t1;
    list=t2;
}
```

Above is a fully working code.
I want to know if there can be further enhancement to the above code?

Comment: have a look @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you make your linked list a double linked list, that is, each node has a pointer to the next one and the previous and if you keep pointers to the first and last node, you won't need to reverse it. Just travel it backawards using the backwards pointers....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Make your indentation and whitespace usage consistent
- Use meaningful identifiers rather than `t1`, `t2` and `t3`
- Make the `data` member a generic type, for example `void *` rather than `int`.
- Don't use global variables, pass `struct node *` pointers to your functions.

Comment: +1 ... and **don't use global variables** is a BIG improvement

Comment: @pmg why is use of global variables a problem?

Comment: @Registered: without globals you know `foo(&bar)` will only change `bar`'s value; with globals any (global) variable can change. Also read [Global Variables Are Bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).